# How to know an event handled by User or Application Methods?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls

I have a [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like a [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) and several events declared for that.

For example:
[CellEndEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx), [CellLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave(v=vs.110).aspx), [RowLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowleave(v=vs.110).aspx), [RowsAdded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx), [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), ... .

Now, when I want to insert several records to the grid, there was also [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for every one of them is executed, while I did not want to call [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) events!
This is only an example of my problems in events.

In summary, my question is, How to know this event handling causes is a user or application methods are executed that ?
In other words, How to know this [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event runs by user or a method called that ?

Comment: Use a boolean flag indicating events are fired from a method call

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it is not good idea, fill all project by flag fields!

Comment: There is no other generic way to solve your problem. If you found one please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I need one interface method between handler and listener methods. For example: `myControl.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => JustCallByUser(myControl_SelectionChanged(s, e))`.             thanks a lot for your anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answer work correctly:

```
public void JustCallEventByUser<TEventArgs>(Action<object, TEventArgs> method, object sender, TEventArgs e) where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    var frames = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrames();

    if (frames == null) return;

    //
    // This method (frames[0]= 'JustCallEventByUser') and declaration listener method (frames[1]= '(s, e)=>') must be removed from stack frames
    if (!frames.Skip(2).Any(x =>
    {
        Type declaringType = x.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
        return declaringType != null && declaringType.Name == this.Name;
    }))
    {  method.Invoke(sender, e); }
}
```

I create a method to play interface character between listener and events. In that I check the [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to know who call me to run a listener !

For example of usage:

```
gridViewMain.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
         JustCallEventByUser(gridViewMain_SelectionChanged, s, e);
```

Please express your comments! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but I solved such problem by creating a method which makes in the control what I want (edit a cell, leave a cell, leave a row, add a row, change the selection... in your example) ignoring the event handler.

For example, if i have a TextBox and I want to update it without listening to the event text changed I do something like this:

```
    textBox.TextChanged -= eventHandler;
    textBox.Text = text;
    textBox.TextChanged += eventHandler;
```

You can capsule it in a method like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns text to textBox.Text ignoring the event handler eventHandler for the event TextChanged.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">Text box control.</param>
    /// <param name="eventHandler">Event handler to ignore.</param>
    /// <param name="text">Text to assign.</param>
    public static void AssignSilently(TextBox textBox, EventHandler eventHandler, string text)
    {
        textBox.TextChanged -= eventHandler;
        textBox.Text = text;
        textBox.TextChanged += eventHandler;
    }
```

Comment: this is bad idea to remove handler, because there are exist many events! and if occurred one exception then all events lost!

Comment: I need a methods to call events from that, and its decided to run or not!

Comment: I think I don't quite understand your last comment. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: I need one interface method between handler and listener methods. For example: `myControl.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => JustCallByUser(myControl_SelectionChanged(s, e))`